# How to supply parameters to the cloudformation.createStack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

As it is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#createStack-property), there is a way to create and deploy a stack using a cloudformation template. What I do not understand is how to supply custom parameters, e.g., `userPoolName`, `autoVerifiedAttributes`, or `mfaConfiguration`.

I would greatly appreciate your help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool thatyou will use to create and deploy stack will expose this functionality.

For eg. If you are using AWS CLI, you can do it in the following manner:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack  --stack-name startmyinstance  
    --template-body file://home/ec2-user/templates/startmyinstance.json 
    --parameters  ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=MyKey ParameterKey=InstanceType,ParameterValue=t1.micro
```

Read more about this in this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/passing-parameters-to-cloudformation-stacks-with-the-aws-cli-and-powershell/) or the official CLI [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html).

To learn more about parameters themself, you can refer the AWS Cloudformation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

If you are using AWS Python SDK, Boto3 you can find it accessable as a parameter like so:

```
response = client.update_stack(
    StackName='string',
    Parameters=[
        {
            'ParameterKey': 'string',
            'ParameterValue': 'string',
            'UsePreviousValue': True|False,
            'ResolvedValue': 'string'
        },
    ],
)
```

Read more about this in the official docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.update_stack). Same goes for SDK for any other language.

Edit 1: Added example for Python - Boto3

Comment: Thanks, but I am using AWS SDK not CLI

Comment: @SaidAkh, I've added example for Python, Boto3. If the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.

Comment: @SaidAkh, if the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.